# how to move camera position in maps from activity

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I have this method in map fragment

```
public static void animateToLocation(final double latitude, final double longtitude) {
    animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longtitude), 12.0f));

}
```

I access the third method from activity like this:

```
FragmentMap.animateToLocation(lat, Lang);
```

When I call method from fragment with button click, it works well. The problem i am having is when I want to call it from activity camera does not move.

Comment: i forgot to write map. in second line

Comment: I fixed your spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's wrong. I defined `map` in `Fragment` but I want to access `animateToLocation` in `fragment` from another activity. Now I define map `public` and when I want to animate cam, I can call it. It works for me from anywhere I want.